# Localizing wordpress theme website

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress.

I just acquired a WordPress theme site from a template site. I installed it on the live site on the root and it's working fine.

I now want to develop the site further on my local laptop. I downloaded the site and installed it with wamp.

I then changed the settings in the tables:

```
UPDATE pref_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE pref_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com');
UPDATE pref_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com', 'http://www.newdomain.com');
```

The problem now is that although the home page and the `/wp-admin/` are working, none of the other pages on the site are working.

Each time I click a link (like the About Us page) it takes me to the wamp server page.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? Is there something  else that needs to be changed to make the sub pages work?

I am also still getting this error message on my home page:

```
fatal error: load error: failed to find /home/wwwseven/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme53857/style.less
```

This clearly means that the system is still looking for the CSS files with the setting of the live site. Where would this be likely set on the system? I mean, I've changed everything in the tables, so I am unclear why it's still doing that.

Comment: Can you please post, for exmple "about us" link?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace all the references to your remote site with the local link. Use a tool like https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB to perform replace in your database. There is no need to change the settings in the table, as you've done presently.